# Symfony 4 translation

Tags: symfony, browser, translation, translate

I've been trying to work with this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html

But seems like no one have any problems with the translations, I must get it totally wrong.

My locale is set to 'fr' in 'services.yaml'

I have my message.en.xlf and message.fr.xlf

Here is my .fr:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="homepage_presta">
                <source>homepage.presta</source>
                <target>Les prestations</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
 </xliff>
```

Been trying in controller (getting "missing translation key" warning):

```
var_dump($translator->trans("homepage_presta"));
```

or in twig:

```
{{ 'homepage.presta'|trans }}
```

But nothing is working..  In the end I would like to translate to the right language depending on the browser language, then to some lang if selected in the navbar (like in a cookie ?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/translation")
 */
public function translationAction(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    dump($translator->trans("homepage.presta"));

    return new Response('<html><body>testaroni</body></html>');
}
```

works for me... a few things...

1. the default translation domain is messages not message so your file should be translations/messages.fr.xlf
2. I'm not used to xlf but it seems you have to use `<source>homepage.presta</source>` for your translation not the id `homepage_presta`
3. Don't forget to clear your cache every time you create a new translation file `php bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: Thanks, missed the "s" in my file.. Thought filename didn't matter :s